Spring batch xml config to java conf
I am trying to transform this xml conf of SpringBatch steps into a Java (Spring batch conf):
<batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
    <batch:tasklet>
    <batch:chunk reader="sqlItemReader" writer="cvsFileItemWriter" commit-interval="10000"/>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>

I already built the reader and writer.
How do you write the step + tasklet + chunk thing in Java?
I have issue finding the commit interval property in Spring batch properties.
